# SQL Query that finds the position of an empty column in an array of 4 columns

Tags: sql

I have four columns and one row in a table; I want use a SQL query to return a number (0-4) that identifies the first column (left to right) that is null or empty. 
For example if columns 1, 2 and 3 contain data, the query would return "4". 
If columns 1 and 4 contain data, the query would return "2". 
If none of the columns contain data, the result should be "1". 
If they all contain data, then "0"
Is there a logical solution for all 16 combinations that wouldn't require explicitly testing each possibility?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? How do you get 16 combinations? There are only 5 possible results.

Comment: Your logic makes no sense to me... If 1, 2,& 3 then 4; if 1 & 4 then 2, if none then 1, if all then 0? How does that identify the first column that's null or empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select case
    when a is null then 1
    when b is null then 2
    when c is null then 3
    when d is null then 4
    else 0 end as FirstNull
from sometable
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing really simple (you're looking for a kind of dual of COALESCE):

You can use the searched CASE, though:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN col2 IS NULL then 2
        WHEN col3 IS NULL then 3
        WHEN col4 IS NULL then 4
    ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

To check all 16 combinations at once, use this:

```
SELECT ( IF(a IS NULL, 8, 0)
       + IF(b IS NULL, 4, 0)
       + IF(c IS NULL, 2, 0)
       + IF(d IS NULL, 1, 0)
       ) AS fullcheck            --takes values from 0 to 15
FROM yourTable
;
```

Column `fullcheck` will be 15 if all four fields are NOT NULL,
0 if all have data.